# Not Able to read Xml data using pyspark to a dataframe

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have an xml file through which I have to read the data into the pyspark. I am using spark-xml api to read it but it's not working. [The link is here for git repository](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml).

I have used the python api but it is not showing the result and throws an exception.

> ```
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.databricks.spark.xml.
> Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
> ```

```
df = spark.read \
.format('com.databricks.spark.xml') \
.options(rowTag='Receipt') \
.load('***.XML', schema = customSchema)
```

When I go to the link it suggests, it shows nothing for the xml.

Finally, I want to read the xml file and then store it to the pyspark dataframe.

Comment: Try: `df = spark.read.format('xml').options(rowTag='Receipt').load('***.XML', schema = customSchema)`

Comment: Yes , I have tried that earlier as well , but it won't work .

Answer (score 0):

Issues seems like spark-xml jar is not available

1) Try creating spark session by setting extra classpath with jar file location

```
jar_path = "<path_of_jar>/com.databricks_spark-xml_2.10-0.4.1.jar"
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Spark - XML read").master("local[*]") \
    .config("spark.jars", jar_path) \
    .config("spark.executor.extraClassPath", jar_path) \
    .config("spark.executor.extraLibrary", jar_path) \
    .config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", jar_path) \
    .getOrCreate()
```

2) Launch pyspark shell by providing spark xml package

`pyspark   --packages com.databricks:spark-xml_2.10:0.4.1`